# Splitting arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a 2D array in Python either a normal one or a numpy array with dimensions (150, 5), I wish to split it into two arrays of dimensions (150, 3) and (150, 2) respectively. Somehow I haven't been able to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for numpy arrays you can slice them like this:

```
a, b = the_array[...,:3], the_array[...,3:]
```

and with lists of lists (that's what I understand for "normal arrays")

```
a, b = [i[:3] for i in the_array], [i[3:] for i in the_array]
```